# Android - create parameter in increment

Tags: java, android

```
        EditText edText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text4);
        EditText edText5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text5);
        EditText edText6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text6);
        EditText edText7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text7);
        EditText edText8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text8);
        EditText edText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text9);
        EditText edText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text10);
        EditText edText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text11);
        EditText edText12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text12);
        EditText edText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text13);
        EditText edText14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text14);
        //........

        EditText edText65 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text65);

        EditText[] editList = {edText4, edText5, edText6, edText7, edText8, edText9, edText10, edText11, edText12, edText13, edText14...edText65};


        for (EditText view : editList){
            view.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
        }
```

Besides create it line by line, how to code it more efficient or better way, so I could setup listener to each `EditText`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is.

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 4; i <= 65; i++) {
      EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(
               getResources().getIdentifier("f1text" + i, "id", "package_name"));
      editTextList.add(editText);
}
```

Which will fetch all the **EditText** sequentially. and do your task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about android's `R.id` but below is what you might want to do:

```
List<EditText> editTextList = new ArrayList<>();

for(i = 0; i < R.id.f1text.length; i++) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.f1text[i]);
    editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
    editTextList.add(editText);
}
```

This answer '[how to get R.id's in the int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424994/how-to-get-r-ids-in-the-int-array#answer-9425397)' you might want to use to create R.id as array.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figure out another way to achieve what i intend to(setup listner to each EditText in the page):

```
ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.f1entrygroup);
        for (int i = 0, count = group.getChildCount(); i < count; ++i) {
            View view = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                view.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusListener);
            }
        }
```